# Can't get CSV to align with shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

Formatted this CSV data and tried to add it to an existing QGIS project and for the life of me can't get the data to align. Project reference is Illinois East NAD 83. Have tried that for the CSV layer as well as EPSG:4326.

Data sets here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f6f53jvii6zgaky/AABLZlf0Fnclq3BQl9DkiGWna?dl=0

Comment: Use the FIELD_12 for X and LOCATION for Y - they're reversed - as well as WGS 84 / 4326 and they will line up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could to use "Delimited Text"

- X Field = field_12
- Y Field = LOCATION
- Geometry CRS = EOSG:4326 - WGS 84

[image]

The result

[image]